# Can't resolve 'css-loader' - Webpack Getting Started Error

Tags: css, webpack, css-loader

Following exactly the getting started guide on the webpack site I run into this error on build:

> **ERROR in ./src/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'css-loader' in 'C:\Users\Dominik\Desktop\tutorial'  @ ./src/index.js
>   2:0-21 webpack.config.js**

The `css-loader` is installed locally. It is registered in the `package.json`. What Im I doing wrong?

```js
    const path = require("path");

    module.exports = {
      entry: "./src/index.js",
      output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
          }
        ]
      }
    };
```

**package.json**

```
    {
      "name": "tutorial",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "build": "webpack"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "css-loader": "^3.4.0",
        "style-loader": "^1.1.1",
        "webpack": "^4.41.4",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "lodash": "^4.17.15"
      }
    }
```

**index.js**

```js
    import _ from "lodash";
    import "./style.css";

    function component() {
      const element = document.createElement("div");

      element.innerHTML = _.join(["Hello", "webpack"], " ");
      element.classList.add("hello");

      return element;
    }

    document.body.appendChild(component());
```

**style.css**

```css
    .hello {
      color: red;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try re-running `npm install --save-dev css-loader`. Can you see it in your `node_modules` folder?

**EDIT**

Uninstalling and re-installing the module fixed it:

`npm remove css-loader && npm install --save-dev css-loader`

Comment: Tried. Again. No success. Yes. It's there.

Comment: Okay. I don't know what happened. But uninstalling it with `npm uninstall --save-dev css-loader` and installing it again made the trick.

Comment: Yes, as I suspected, something not quite right with how it was installed originally :)

Comment: Initial install was: `npm install --save-dev style-loader css-loader` I copied it from [webpack getting started site](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/).